# PropertyChangedEvent firing multiple times

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling

I have a class with several properties. When these are changed, a `PropertyChangedEvent` raised. Some properties depend on other properties, so when one of the dependencies is changed, it raises a `PropertyChangedEvent` for itself, and for the property that depends on it.

My problem is, that I have attached a `PropertyChangedEventHandler` to an instance of this class. When one of the properties that is depended upon by another property, this event handler is called several times. Is there a way to get around this?

**UPDATE**

A little code, just to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
    private bool _foo;
    private bool _bar;

    public bool Foo
    {
        get { return _foo; }
        set
        {
            _foo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Foo");
            OnPropertyChanged("Baz");
        }
    }

    public bool Bar
    {
        get { return _bar; }
        set
        {
            _bar = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Bar");
            OnPropertyChanged("Baz");
        }
    }

    public bool Baz
    {
        get
        {
            return Foo && Bar;
        }
    }
```

When `Foo` is set, `Baz` changes as well. If I attach a `PropertyChangedEventHandler`, this will be called twice, when I set `Foo`. I only want to call it once. Is there a nice way around it?

Comment: It looks perfectly logical to me. You shouldn't mute all that events: when the property have changed, it should trigger the change event. How do you need to handle it? What is happening in the EventHandler? Why do you want to ignore other handlers?

Comment: you should not raise another property changed from another one. You should from the setter of Property 1 trigger a method to update Property 2 which by changing will trigger his own property change. I use that alot and noticed it goes better if you call other property update before callin your current property `notifypropertychanged`

Comment: I added a little code, to illustrate what I'm talking about.

Comment: oh you meant that way. The other way in that case is on your OnPropertyChanged event to check if either Foo or Bar changed and trigger a Baz change event. But your way is also good but you repeat in diferent place as for if you add it in your event all interdependence will be visible in 1 place.

Comment: That's a good point! As I see it, they each have their benefits. What I will probably do, is to use the multi-notifier in @Sheridan's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is think logically about this issue for a moment to get your answer. You have the following situation:

```
public bool Foo
{
    get { return _foo; }
    set
    {
        _foo = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Foo");
        OnPropertyChanged("Baz");
    }
}

public bool Bar
{
    get { return _bar; }
    set
    {
        _bar = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Bar");
        OnPropertyChanged("Baz");
    }
}

public bool Baz
{
    get
    {
        return Foo && Bar;
    }
}
```

My first comment is that if you *are* going to raise your `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event more than once at a time, then you'd be better off using an implementation like this, which would enable you to raise the event for as many properties as you like at once:

```
protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames) 
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("Foo", "Bar");
```

So back to your problem... let's think about your requirement:

1. You need to notify the interface when the value of `Baz` changes.

Its value can be changed when either the `Foo` or `Bar` property values change... therefore you'll need to notify the interface when either of them changes, as you have.

Now, @Franck commented to say that *You should from the setter of Property 1 trigger a method to update Property 2 which by changing will trigger his own property change*. Let's think about that for a minute... presumably, you'd need to call this same method from both of the `Foo` or `Bar` property setters to make it work.

However, what would actually happen is that the when the `Foo` and `Bar` values are changed, the method would be called twice and so the `INotifyPropertyChanged` notification will still be called twice, albeit now coming from the `Baz` setter... so clearly, this is no improvement.

There is however, one more option that could work for you. For this to work, you'd need to add a helper method that would update the `Foo` or `Bar` property values *and* notify the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on behalf of the `Baz` property:

```
public void UpdateBaz(bool? foo, bool? bar)
{
    if (foo != null) Foo = foo;
    if (bar != null) Bar = bar;
    OnPropertyChanged("Baz");
}
```

Of course, for this to work, you'd need to remove the call to `OnPropertyChanged("Baz")` from the two property handlers:

```
public bool Foo
{
    get { return _foo; }
    set { _foo = value; OnPropertyChanged("Foo"); }
}

public bool Bar
{
    get { return _bar; }
    set { _bar = value; OnPropertyChanged("Bar"); }
}
```

However, if you want the `Foo` and `Bar` properties to be updated through `Binding`, then you'd be back to @Franck's suggestion of calling this method twice and the two properties are updated individually. In that case, it seems as though you'll just have to put up with the `Baz` property being notified twice.

Comment: Good solution for cleaner multi notify. @torbonde if you plan keeping your original way i suggest this change.

Comment: Thank very much! I like the multi-notify thing very much! However, I don't think I understand the last part of your answer. Where would I call `UpdateBaz`?

Comment: As I mentioned in the last paragraph of my answer... you wouldn't be able to use traditional data binding with this method. If you're not `Binding` the `Foo` and `Bar` properties, then you would call this method from wherever your code updates them. Otherwise, you'll just have to put up with the `Baz` property being notified twice.

Comment: Ah, ok. Unfortunately, I am using binding. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

insert a value changed check in your setter like:

```
set
{
   if(value != [yourfield])
   {
      yourfield = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(Yourfield);
   }
}
```

Comment: And how would that help?

Comment: @KamilT: Actually it's good style anyways, but not doing it might result in unneccessary updates yielding PropChange calls. I haven't seen his code yet...

Comment: it can be a good or bad practice, dependent on what are you trying to achieve ;)

Comment: I'm not sure how that could help me. I have updated my answer to clarify what I meant.

Comment: if you have lots of property this is quite a huge performance hit when loading back object. My experience over couple hundreds object with on to in the fifty property each are about 2 to 3 times slower to load than directly assigning them with basic `field = value`. typically my objects are NOT linked to a view until loaded so the check for if different is completely useless and kills performance anyway. Loading time went down in the 2-3 minutes down from 8 minutes simply by not using the above

Comment: Thats actually hard to believe. Doing a reference equals is like the fastest operation within the framework as long as we are not talking about structures and/or value comparison. Usually OnPropertyChange calls (especially with string.Empty) are the performance problems within large WPF apps in my experience.
But if you are confident about your application structure it might be better to just assign the value. I wouldn't do that though. Still I believe you, that in your case this made a difference.

Comment: we have a compiled model lib of 37 meg so it is the biggest i have ever seen. that's a couple thousand classes so using equal doesn't work by default because it wont compare class within those class properly so you need to override the equals and check specific property by hand which that is the slow part. I also noticed a big performance hit when using WPF over winforms as well. But i am stuck using it per decision made above me :(